# Do we use the article "The" before a war?

Tags: articles

I'm wondering if I have to use "the" before the name of a war or not.

Example:

"in the World War I" or "in World War I"

"in the World War II" or "in World War II"

"in the Civil War" or "in Civil War"

Comment: The rule here is basically the same as for any other noun: if it's a proper noun (like *World War I*) then it doesn't get an article.  If it's a non-proper noun, maybe with an adjective, then it needs an article, because *war* is countable: *the Crimean War, the War of 1812*, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Usually we use "the" as part of the name of the war but there are exceptions.

> "World War One", but "The First World War"

We don't use "the" with "World War One", but we do when talking about "the first..."

> Queen Anne's War, but "The War of Spanish Succession" (1705-1713)

Since the possessive acts as a determiner, we don't use a "the" for Queen Anne's War.

I'll mention a few specific examples of using "the" with names of wars

> The war.

The refers to the last major conflict in a given context. In English speaking counties "The war" is the second world war.

> The Great War

Usually the Eurasian conflict of 1914-1918

> The civil war

In America this would normally be the conflict of 1861-1865 between the Northern and Southern states.  In the UK this would usually be conflict of 1642-1651 between parliamentarians and monarchists.

Note that when used like an adjective, we drop the "the"

> The auction had some civil war armor on sale.