# Why isn't there an article before "conflict"?

Tags: articles, zero-article

Why isn't there an article before *conflict* in the following sentence?

> Difference in the pronouncement leads to conflict.

Comment: I've no idea what "Difference in the pronouncement" is supposed to mean but *Political differences can lead to conflict* is perfectly natural and comprehensible. Note that when used like this, ***conflict*** (and SOME directly replaceable alternatives such as ***war, struggle, dispute,...***) can ***optionally*** be preceded by the indefinite article. This *slightly* changes the meaning by making it more of a "generic" statement, but for most purposes it's just a stylistic choice. Also note that for many similar words *(**quarrel, squabble,...**)* you MUST include the article...

Comment: and for other alternatives *(**strife, antagonism,...**)* you CAN'T include the article

Comment: See [No indefinite article before the word 'battle'](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/151632/) and [In what instances can the word 'war' on its own i.e. without numerals and/or names/titles be used without any article?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/264216/) and [Do we use the article “The” before a war?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/173873/), among others.

Comment: What if I use the article 'a' before it?

Comment: I still have no idea what "Difference in the pronouncement" is supposed to mean. And you haven't edited your question to clarify that point, so I can't say whether including "a" before "it" would make any difference. And I don't even know what you mean by "it" there! Do you mean before the word ***difference***, or before the word ***conflict**?* But PLEASE - before you answer THAT question, explain what "Difference in the pronouncement" is supposed to mean, otherwise I don't think this question is acceptable for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's referring to the general concept of conflict, rather than the specific one.

You could say "leads to *a* conflict" or similar, but in doing so you're making a more specific statement about what sort of conflict it leads to.  Maybe it's a petty conflict, maybe it's a major one.  Maybe it's several years of conflict (see again no article there).

Leaving the article out allows you to be more circumspect.

Comment: For specificity, we use the article 'the'. You said if I put 'a' before conflict, it would be specific. How ?

Comment: @jaidurga In the sense that you are referring to one specific conflict rather than conflict in general.

Answer (score 0):

**"conflict" can be countable or uncountable**.  [Countable and Uncountable Nouns](https://www.gingersoftware.com/content/grammar-rules/nouns/countable-uncountable-nouns/)

***The biggest conflict** of the 20th century was World War II*. (countable)

***Conflict** between countries can escalate into war*. (uncountable)

---

In your rather cryptic sentence we can demonstrate the difference.

*Difference in the pronouncement leads to conflict.* (uncountable)

*Difference in the pronouncement leads to many conflicts.* (countable)